# How to include CMake compatible with Cygwin on CLion on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, cygwin, clion

I'm trying to configure CLion with Cygwin, but I'm having trouble with CMake. The program says that the bundled version doesn't work in that environment and that the CMake from Cygwin is outdated (needs a newer version). However, I tried installing an independant CMake but then the program says it isn't compatible with Cygwin. How do I fix this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7AeL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm teaching a C++ programming class this semester. All of my students were able to successfully install/configure CLion without too much trouble. Most of them are on Windows boxes, Win7 and Win10.

In my instructions, I referred them to this video, which was the best I could find: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2h_976SpV0

Some of the students were missing the debugger the first time they tried this. In the cygwin installer, the number of check boxes is enormous and many of the names are remarkably similar. When we went back through and re-ran the installer, in each case we were able to find a place where they had checked the wrong box.

So my recommendation would be re-run your cygwin installation after watching the video once through. Then go back to the frame in the video where he shows all his checked install options and very carefully compare your checked boxes against the presenter's.

Good luck!